# PHP snackbar using href <a> onClick doesn't work?

Tags: javascript, php

I'm trying to dismiss this snackbar when I click the add to cart `<a href>` but it doesn't output anything. Anyone can help me? here is my code

**SNACKBAR CODE**

```
<div id="snackbar">Some text some message..</div>
```

**A HREF CODE**

```
<a class="btn btn-primary" href="?add=<?php echo($i); ?>" onClick="myFunction()">Add to cart
```

**JQUERY.JS CODE**

```
function myFunction() {
var x = document.getElementById("snackbar")
x.className = "show";
setTimeout(function(){ x.className = x.className.replace("show", ""); }, 3000);
}
```

Comment: your code is not jQuery.

Comment: your code is not php either

Comment: that doesn't make sense .. Why would I still post a php problem if it wasnt php lol..

Comment: people nowadays are too much brainy lol.

Answer (score 1):

Your code doesn't at all make use of jQuery. But if you want to use jQuery the code below is equivalent of jQuery code to your clean js code.

```
function myFunction() {
    var snackbar = $("#snackbar");
    snackbar.addClass("show").delay(3000).removeClass("show");
}
```

Or even better:

```
function myFunction() {
    var snackbar = $("#snackbar");
    snackbar.show().delay(3000).hide();
}
```

a jsfidle example her would have been good.

Answer (score 0):

Use `x.addClass('show')` or `x.removeClass('show')`

Comment: it doesnt show. I'm using a table and it doesnt show although it shows when i remove the button then i'll place it at the top of the code where the table doesn't exists.